# Just started learning math in university. I have to make example groups with A ⊂ {(n, m) : n, m ∈ N} and A∩B = {(i, m) : i = 1, 2 and m ∈ N}

Tags: complex-numbers

So we are learning the basics of ⊂, ∈ , ∩ , ∪  and =.
We have questions in this manner:

"When A, B ⊂ *R*: Give example of groups that work in these terms."

1. A ∩ B = ∅ and A ∪ B = [0, 1)

My answer to this was : "B = { 0 }  and A = { [0, 1) }" , and I got no clue if it is right, but at least I think I understand the basic principle here. (Even if I might have written in completely wrong.)

Anyways, the hard part that I can't wrap my head around is this:

2. A ⊂ {(n, m) : n, m ∈ N} and A∩B = {(i, m) : i = 1, 2 and m ∈ N}

I think it has something to do with the Cartesian numbers (*R^2*), but yeah... I'm not 100% sure what is the difference between Cartesian numbers and Complex numbers for example.

I came up with something like this with my friend:

A = {(n, m) : n = (0, 1,2), m ∈ N}
B = {(i, m) : i ≥ 2 and i, m ∈ N}

Got no idea how to write it, but I hope you get the idea :I

I'm very sorry if this was hard for you to read, I was trying my best to explain the situation in English. Math terms in English ain't my strongest skill.

Comment: I think by R you meant $\mathbb{R}$, the set of real numbers (not Cartesian numbers)? And by "groups that work in these terms", you meant "sets that satisfy these properties". What language do you learn maths in? I suggest you use a maths glossary rather than just a translation software to ask a question here in the future. Good try though.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. For example, try using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your question. Some user will skip your question just because is not written using it.

Comment: Ah roger that. Ill read them through.

Comment: Your answer to (1) is wrong because $\{0\}\cap[0,1)=\{0\}\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: @BenjaminWang Ah yes, thanks. I'm learning it in Finnish. First day doing any of this, so still gathering all the tools to navigate in this world.

Comment: Are you sure $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}?$ Because the second part is asking for $A$ to be a proper subset of a set that contains ordered pairs.